# Missing xcrun ever since upgrading to Mojave while trying to use storyboard compiler without command line

Tags: xcode, xcrun

I keep getting this error:

```
 /xcrun: invalid DEVELOPER_DIR path  
 (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer), missing xcrun at: 
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcrun
```

and I've tried xcode-select --install.  I'm having no luck and I'm stuck, any help would be great.  Here is the error message.

I tried creating a /usr/bin and copying the xcrun executable to that folder, but that didn't help.  I've exhausted all the options I know, and I hate asking for help, but in this case I've been stuck for days on this.

-Thanks

Comment: The error has changed from that to this:    xcrun: error: unable to exec Xcode native xcrun (Permission denied).

Comment: Did you install the Xcode 10 command-line tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Xcode, select Preferences > Locations and make sure Command Line Tools is pointing to Xcode 10.0. This should fix the error you seeing.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!